# Type not supported - The JSON data is not available before MySQL 5.7.8

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running local `MySQL` instance version of `5.7.23` in `Ubuntu-18-04`. The DB is already having some tables having **JSON** fields to store `JSON` data. They working fine with insert, update and delete operations.

The issue comes when try to modify an existing table to have a new field to store **JSON** data. `MySQL-Workbench` is giving an error saying

> **Type not supported**
>
> The JSON data is not available before MySQL 5.7.8.
> In order to use it, first set the version for your model to 5.7.8 or
> higher

Following screen shots shows my local environment information.

**The error:**
[image]

**MySQL server info:**
[image]

**MySQL Workbench info:**
[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was able to figure the issue. The default version set for **Modeling MySQL** was set as **5.6.30**. Changed it to **5.7.8** and works the table schema modification.

Go to `Edit` -> `Preferences...` in **MySQL Workbench**

Refer the below screens:

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Preference` doesn't work for me. I use osx with workbench version 8.0.11.
`Model` in top bar menu -> `Model Options` -> `MySQL` then change the version as Shantha's answer works for me.

[image]

Previous version of MySQLWorkbench (6.3.10) has better error message for this...

Comment: Thank you for posting this as it covers another environment/OS version.